# How to get the info if the ftp path is not accessible?

Tags: powershell, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to download Acrobat Reader from ftp path. Sometimes the ftp path is not responsive. i would like to get the info if it is not responsive.

```
$ftpFolderUrl = "ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/AcrobatDC/"
$ftpRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$ftpFolderUrl")
$ftpRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectory
$ftpResponse = $ftpRequest.GetResponse()
$responseStream = $ftpResponse.GetResponseStream()
```

How to get the info whether ftp is responsive or not?

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use try and catch.
first try to get a response, if that doesn't work, print the exception.
something like that:

```
$ftpFolderUrl = "ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/AcrobatDC/"
$ftpRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$ftpFolderUrl")
$ftpRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectory
try
{
    $ftpResponse = $ftpRequest.GetResponse()
    $responseStream = $ftpResponse.GetResponseStream()
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception | format-list -force
}
```

this will print out any error.
If you want to get fancy, you can now play with the thrown errors and catch them separately.

Therefore, take a look at this page: [try and catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6) and [exceptions](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/01/print-full-exception-powershell-trycatch-block-using-format-list/).

Hope this helps